# Load Text Files as Binary Using MarkLogic REST APIs

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to load a text file, regardless of its content, as a binary document through the MarkLogic REST APIs? More specifically through a resource extension end point?

I see it is possible through the `xdmp:document-load` function but not quite sure how to do it using the REST APIs.

```
xdmp:document-load("C:\my\path\test.txt",
    map:map() => map:with("uri", "/test/test.txt")
              => map:with("format", "binary")
)
```

I have tried to load the same document through the `PUT /v1/documents` API and set the `format` parameter to be `binary`. But it was still loaded as a `text` file.

The use case is that I need to ingest a bunch of attachment files which occasionally include some text files. I don't need MarkLogic to index their content and in fact many of those files have encoding or format issues if MarkLogic attempts to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have encoding issues with your text files, that is often an indication that an incorrect character encoding is being used somewhere in the process of loading and processing content. I would focus on figuring out what is going wrong there, rather than try to avoid the issue by saving as binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With /v1/documents PUT, the `format` parameter is used to indicate the format of the metadata, not the document.

As described in [Controlling Input and Output Content Type](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_22986)

> - Primary: URI extension MIME type mapping, as long as the request does not specify a transform function.
> - Fallback: Content-type header MIME type mapping. For multipart input, the request Content-type header must be multipart/mixed, so the Content-type header for each part specifies the MIME type of the content for that part.

The resource file extension from the document URI is used to look for a configured Mimetype. It will use the `format` for the configured Mimetype, if there is a matching entry.

Unfortunately, the explicit `Content-type` header does not override the implicit `format` determination. So, if you want to load document that have a `.txt` file extension as `binary()` documents then you will need to implement some workarounds.

In order to load the text documents as `binary()` with `/v1/documents PUT` you could:

- Use a different file extension. Append ".bin" to the end of the text file URIs i.e. `/myTextFile.txt.bin`. That may not be desired, since it does change the URI of the documents from what it really is, but does indicate that the text doc is being stored as a binary document.
- Apply a custom transformation when loading the documents and specify the desired 
  `Content-type`

An example of a passthrough transform that could be applied, so that the implicit URL `format` detection is not applied, and the explicit `Content-type` header is applied:

```
function noop(context, params, content){
  return content;
} 
exports.transform=noop
```

After [installing the custom transform](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_86618) with the name `noop`:
Below is an example curl command that installs the noop transform. Update the username/password as appropriate:

```
curl --anyauth --user myUsername:myPassword -X PUT -i -d "function noop(context, params, content){return content;} exports.transform=noop" -H "Content-type: application/vnd.marklogic-javascript" http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/transforms/noop
```

It is then possible to invoke `/v1/documents PUT` and specify `Content-type` as a binary Mimetype (in this example, as `application-octet-stream`):

```
curl --anyauth --user myUsername:myPassword -T ./test.txt -i -H "Content-type: application/octet-stream" "http://localhost:8000/v1/documents?uri=/test.txt&transform=noop"
```

and it will be loaded as `binary()` instead of `text()`

```
doc("/test.txt")/node()/xdmp:node-kind(.)
```

yields: `binary`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and the solutions!